# Notepad Ctrl-Backspace behavior

Tags: shortcuts, notepad, characters, control-characters

Text fields in almost all software erase a word when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> is pressed. However, Notepad behaves differently, and inserts a character which is:
`` (I copy-pasted it here. I'm not sure if it is visible. It looks like a rectangle in Notepad.)

Here is a screenshot:

[image: ctrl+bksp]

- What is this character?
- Why does Notepad do this? Is it simpler to implement?
- Are there other key combinations for other characters?
- Is there a key combination in Notepad for erasing a word?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. It's [0x7F "Delete"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) in ASCII and [U+007F "Delete"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7f/index.htm) in Unicode.
2. It's in fact *lack of* an implementation. Plain <kbd>Backspace</kbd> sends an ASCII 0x08 (I'm not sure how the Edit control handles it internally), and it is not uncommon in various operating systems for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> to send the "Delete" sequence.

   The "delete word" behavior was added later, [as an undocumented feature](http://web.archive.org/web/2008if_/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/11/5395501.aspx), and only to those Edit controls which use "SHAutoComplete". If a textbox has autocompletion disabled, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> will likely not work.

   (<s>Some</s>Many programs implement *their own* text editing controls, which work slightly differently from the built-in one.)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> will get translated to a newline ([`^J` is CR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) in ASCII and `^M` is LF; however, the Edit control translates both *keypresses* to CR+LF.) Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> inserts a Tab character.

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> will result in somewhat useless "Unit separator" (`^_`) and "Record separator" (`^^`).

   (The `^X` notation means the Ctrl key – Ctrl-X in this example – in ASCII this is equivalent to unsetting the 7th bit of the following character.)
4. No, but you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>← Left</kbd> to *select* the previous word, and overwrite by typing.

   Or get a [better Notepad](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response grawity. But I don't understand why you rejected @RJFalconer's edit. [Ctrl][Left] does not _select_ without [Shift].

Comment: @musa: I didn't, that just happens when two people are editing at once.

Comment: Just for the record: Notepad2 has exactly the same problem in the Find and Replace Text dialogs that Notepad(++) has, Ctrl-Backspace does not delete the previous word. The workaround works perfect, thanks.

Comment: @user1686 The "undocumented feature" link doesn't lead anywhere useful (archive content notification).

Answer (score 8):

Ctrl-Backspace to delete a word in Notepad has been finally been implemented!

See the changes to Notepad in Windows 10 version 1809. [Here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/new-improved-windows-10-notepad/)

Comment: Wow, finally! Even though I rarely use plain notepad (when I forgot to change the default app to open with) I‘m still annoyed. I should install this update then.
For anyone coming here in the future: 1809 was rolled out in November 2018.