# When using the Find and Replace window in Excel, the Ctrl-Backspace adds a weird character

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing

Normally, inside a textbox, the shortcut `Ctrl+Backspace` deletes the previous word, but in the Excel Find and Replace window, it doesn't work and it inserts a character with a rectangular shape.

[image]

Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to change that. This is part of a legacy behavior that was also present in Notepad before it was removed in 2018. It might eventually get patched in Excel as well.

The weird character in question is the ASCII "DELETE" control character (0x7F); more info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/332026/notepad-ctrl-backspace-behavior/332034#332034).